# How can i localized html or php source code from wordpress

Tags: localization

I wonder how can finde html/php source to change , word name from Read More to just More.

http://www.wyprawykulturowe.pl/2016/08/17/tropikalna-wyspa/

This is the site this image block on bottom have some description and of end of it is Read More that i wanna change to just More . How can i do it?

THanks!

Comment: Your site is infected and blocked by browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="color:#333;" class="read-more" href="">Read More</a>
```

From the inline style and class I cannot find in WP core it seems to be custom developed. You would have to searches through the sources of your site to locate code responsible (likely theme, but might not be).

PS FYI Chrome blocks access to your site with malware warning.

Comment: This read more comes from wordpress plugin "Team" i search in team folder but can't find this some how

Answer (score 0):

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">More</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

This code snippet Copied from WordPress codex. [Vist](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) this page to read more.

Comment: The output in example page provided is not consistent with native more links though. I doubt it uses them.

Comment: Yes but , this image block are form plugin i search in plugin files for that code to change it and can't find anything